# How to Make default value of single line of text be read-only on in SharePoint online modern list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, spo

How to Make default value of single line of text be read-only on in SharePoint online modern list.

I have the same requirement as mention in this post and have to implement this in the modern list, any suggestion on how to achieve this.

[Make default value of single line of text be read-only on new/edit form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242122/make-default-value-of-single-line-of-text-be-read-only-on-new-edit-form)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To customize SharePoint Online modern list form, PowerApps will be needed. Instead of adding a single text column, you can directly add a label to the form and displaying the instructions you need.

Something to start with PowerApps:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFzd5qwS4-c